# GAE Blobstore File Upload with additional form fields - Slim3

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

Using Google's Slim3 and Blobstore, I can successfully upload files to blobstore using the:

```
blobstore.createUploadUrl("myUrlToReturnTo")
```

AppEngine successfully redirects back to the url I specify and everything works fine except the code to process the additional form fields the blobstore is supposed to pass on to my servlet/controller after processing the file out of the form. Slim3 controller code for accessing form fields:

```
String textField = asString("textfield")
```

Looked and looked and seems like I have everything right, but it appears I am stuck.

Comment: what is slim3, it seems you are almost there?

Comment: @peterretief - Slim3 is a lightweight MVC & datastore framework from Google for AppEngine.  https://sites.google.com/site/slim3appengine/